# Connecting to IIS on Hyper-V Windows 8 host from XP virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8

I have a windows 8 machine running an XP virtual machine with Hyper-V.  The virtual machine uses an 'external' virtual switch, and after 'Integration Services Setup', it can see the internet ok. My machine is on a static IP address (10.0.0.199) and I can ping that IP address from the virtual machine. I host a website on my Windows 8 machine with IIS8 at localhost:57868, however even with the XP and Windows 8 firewalls off I cannot connect to `http://10.0.0.199:57868` from the virtual machine.

Any ideas? Should this be possible with this setup?  How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Not to ask silly questions, but have you turned off all the windows software based firewalls?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely IIS running on the Virtual Machine.
Did you: 
Reset IIS
Check to make sure that the web server is configured to respond on port 57868?
If you are not sure, try hitting http://10.0.0.199.  If you have success, then check your port bindings